# Pass String to a method that accepts an UnsafeRawPointer parameter

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone know why every time `processUnsafeRawPointer(key)` is executed, the printed result is different?

What happens when passing `String` directly to a method that accepts an `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter?

```
var key = "Key"

func jump() {
    print("\ntest UnsafeRowPointer")
    processUnsafeRawPointer(key)
    processUnsafeRawPointer(&key)
}

func processUnsafeRawPointer(_ key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    print(key)
}

public static func main() {
    jump()
    jump()
    jump()
}
```

Console:

```
test UnsafeRowPointer
0x0000600000c104a0
0x000000010000d3c0

test UnsafeRowPointer
0x0000600000c104a0
0x000000010000d3c0

test UnsafeRowPointer
0x0000600000c18020
0x000000010000d3c0
```

Answer (score 2):

What actually happens is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/calling-functions-with-pointer-parameters):

> When you call a function that is declared as taking an
> `UnsafePointer<Type>` argument, you can pass any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - A `String` value, if Type is `Int8` or `UInt8`. The string is automatically converted to UTF8 in a zero-terminated buffer, and a
>   pointer to that buffer is passed to the function.
> - An in-out expression that contains a mutable variable, property, or subscript reference of type `Type`, which is passed as a pointer to
>   the address of the left-hand side identifier.
>
> ...
>
> When you call a function that takes an `UnsafeRawPointer` argument,
> you can pass the same operands as `UnsafePointer<Type>`, but with any
> type as `Type`.

`processUnsafeRawPointer(key)` is the "a `String` value" case. A buffer will be created. This buffer is allocated somewhere in memory, and doesn't have to be the same location every time.

`processUnsafeRawPointer(&key)` is the "an in-out expression" case. Since `key` is a `var`, this will just pass the location of the `var`, without doing anything else.